# Using CoffeeScript, Bower, RequireJS and concatination together

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, requirejs, concatenation, bower

I am kind of confused how to use the following together:

- CoffeeScript
- Bower
- RequireJS
- Concatination

Should I be (using Grunt):

1. Compiling CoffeeScript into JS into some temp folder
2. Copy bower components into some temp folder
3. Using RequireJS to concat the above generated files
4. Remove the temp folder

Is there a more direct way without the temp folder? Is there an automated way to identify which files in bower components are actually required? Often, there are other files, like minified, non-minified or non-concatenated copies.

Comment: If the Bower packages are also on NPM I would just go with Browserify

Comment: We do all of that except to a "dist" directory to distribute the compiled output. We leave the generated JS in place because we generate source maps with RequireJS which point back to that which is helpful when debugging. This workflow would be a pain without a build tool like Grunt

Answer (score 0):

Use the require-cs plugin for correctly handling and compiling coffee-script files.

Define your modules like so:

```
define([
  'cs!lasers'       // lasers.coffee
], (lasers) ->
  // do stuff with lasers
```

Also, Your requirejs config should have a `exclude: ['coffee-script']` attribute like so:

```
requirejs:
  devBuild:
    options:
      baseUrl: 'src/apps'
      stubModules: ['cs']
      include: [
        'text'
        'cs!components'
      ]
      exclude: ['coffee-script']
      out: 'src/lib/app.js'
      paths:
        .
        .
        .
        cs: '../public/components/require-cs/cs'
        'coffee-script': '../public/components/coffee-script/index'
        .
        .
        .
```

And you are good to go. Run with `grunt requirejs:devBuild`